# Docker assign a public IP for single container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I installed docker to install over a container for each site I created only that to access port 80 I need each container to have its own public IP.
How can I create a bridge network to correctly assign each container its public IP?

Currently I have seen that there is the subnet created by default by docker on class 172.17.0.0/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a **bridged network** as explaine [in the official guide](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) like follow:

```sh
docker network create my-net

docker create --name my-nginx \
  --network my-net \
  --publish 8080:80 \
  my-image
```

Or, if you prefer using **docker compose**, please refer to [Docker compose networking guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).